# Count distinct elements from a concurrently read stream

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, stdmap, stdset

I have multiple listeners threads reading a stream of messages (Kafka). Each message has an identifier. The consumers/stream guarantees at-least once consumption. At most of the time, the stream would provide the message exactly once. The count of messages to expect is known beforehand. When all messages are received, I want to shutdown all listener threads. The number of messages can be at most 50 million. What data structure is most suitable for this?

I was thinking of using `std::set`, `std::map` and using a `mutex` at each insertion of the thread. Can a single thread be actually faster in such a use-case? Is there something more optimal?

Comment: Ring buffer, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unordered_map` would be better. But you should consider using something like **HyperLogLog**